# I cant get the Facebook profile picture

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I can get this profile picture:

name: João
imageUrl: https://graph.facebook.com/10203753095165506/picture?width=80&height=80

but i cant get this profiles picture:

name: Miguel
imageUrl: https://graph.facebook.com/10152412025465080/picture?width=80&height=80
name: Diogo
imageUrl: https://graph.facebook.com/10154199532995368/picture?width=80&height=80
name: Hugo
imageUrl: https://graph.facebook.com/10152525870872848/picture?width=80&height=80

I'm getting this error:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) No node specified",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}

Can you help?

Comment: those pages don't exist hence there is no picture related to it

Comment: This or privacy settings.

Comment: Where did you get those IDs? they're definitely not active users

Comment: I get this using FBGraphUser.id (iOS) and send it to a database.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing but neither of those 3 are user ids.

Comment: I think I have the same problem. It happens only with the id of the logged-in user. Have you managed to solve this ?

Comment: Hi, are you trying to retrieve the id from a database?